# Splitting an htmlParse'd HTML document while preserving the class

Tags: r, xml-parsing

I'd like to scrap phone numbers from [this French public directory](http://www.pagesjaunes.fr). The thing is, it can return multiple answers, and I'd like to get them all, but I have a problem in the splitting of the parsed HTML doc.

Here is my code :

```
  # example url for reproducibility 
  url_ <- "http://www.pagesjaunes.fr/recherche/departement/zc-de-vignolles-beaune-21/pagot-&-savoie---espace-aubade"
  response <- GET(url_)
  doc <- content(response, type="text/html", encoding = "UTF-8")
  parseddoc <- htmlParse(doc)

  # I think the problem lies in this next line, let's call it "line A" : 
  boxes <- xpathSApply(parseddoc, "//article[@class='bi-bloc blocs clearfix  bi-pro']")

  foreach(box = boxes) %do% {
    # and also in this line, let's call it "line B" :
    return_line$PJ_phone_number <- xpathApply(box, "//div[@class='item bi-contact-tel']", xmlValue)
  }
}
```

I've tested line A, the `xpathSApply()` gets all the nodes with the XPath `"//article[@class='bi-bloc blocs clearfix  bi-pro']"` (which is basically each box of result from the search on the website) and puts them into a list. I'm then going through this list with `foreach`. (I've tested this)

However, for line B to work, "box" needs to be of class `"XMLInternalDocument"`. (`parseddoc` has class `"HTMLInternalDocument" "HTMLInternalDocument" "XMLInternalDocument" "XMLAbstractDocument"` for instance). But in line A, `xpathSApply()` returns a list of objects of class `"XMLInternalElementNode" "XMLInternalNode" "XMLAbstractNode"`.

So my question is, how can I have line A "split" the parts of `parseddoc` that I need, also while keeping the same class, `XMLInternalDocument` ?

I hope I'm clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: Does it do what you want if you replace `box` with `xmlDoc(box)` on line B?

Comment: Nope. I'm sorry, I forgot to quote the error message : `Error in { : task 1 failed - "replacement has 0 rows, data has 1"`

Comment: Well, your code example is not complete, but it seems you are not using the foreach construct correctly. Please read `?foreach`, particularly the part around `it's purpose is to return a value (a list, by default), rather than to cause side-effects`. The assignment you have on line B is a side effect. I think this is a different issue than your initial question.

Comment: It is, I did not include the full code but I'm doing other things after line B in the foreach loop.